# Express Session use leads to a requires a middleware function

Tags: node.js, express, express-session

I am attempting to implement sessions and passport.js on a small test website to see how to use user authentication.

```
var express = require("express");
var expressSession = require("express-sessions");
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var passport = require("passport");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var LocalStrategy = require("passport-local");
var passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose");
var User = require("./models/user");
var app = express();

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/authDemoApp");
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
extended: true}));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

app.use(expressSession({
secret: "This is one hell of a secret",
resave: false,
saveUninitialized: false
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());

app.listen(3000, function () {
console.log("Its running!!!");
});
```

The error that I get i:

```
throw new TypeError('app.use() requires a middleware function')
^
TypeError: app.use() requires a middleware function
```

I added call back function to `app.use(expressSession...)` making it:

```
app.use(function(err){
if (err){
console.log(err);
}else {
expressSession(...
}
});
```

The `err` value came back with:

```
IncomingMessage {
 _readableState:
ReadableState {
objectMode: false,
highWaterMark: 16384,
buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },
length: 0,
pipes: null,
pipesCount: 0,
```

etc...

My question is middleware function and how do I add it to the `app.use(expressSession etc...` ?

Comment: app.use takes a callback, that has `req`, `res`, and `next` as arguments.

Comment: @DakshMiglani so do I need something like `app.use(function(req,res,next){expressSesions({etc....})});` ?

Comment: first let's establish what you're trying to exactly do, why don't you directly use it like `app.use(expressSession(args))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The module is [`express-session`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session), but your require statement is loading `express-sessions`.

Correcting this, the program runs.

```
var express = require("express");
var expressSession = require("express-session");
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var passport = require("passport");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var app = express();

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/authDemoApp");
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

app.use(expressSession({
  secret: "This is one hell of a secret",
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log("Its running!!!");
});
```

There is even a Github issue for it. [#446 app.use() requires middleware functions](https://github.com/expressjs/session/issues/446)

Comment: When I changed it,  I got `Cannot find module 'express-session'` . On top of that everything uses the name `express-sessions`.

Comment: kindly do a `npm install express-session` and re-run the program

Comment: I just installed `npm install express-session` and it worked thank you i  must have done `npm install express-sessions`.